# Converting an xml into list of anonymous object

Tags: c#, xml, linq, lambda, xml-parsing

I have an xml which contain the language details like

```
<LanguageList>
   <Language code = "EN-US" name = "English - United Sates"></Language>
   <Language code = "EN-UK" name = "English - United Kingdom"></Language>
    --
    --
</LanguageList>
```

I want to convert this into a list of anonymous objects where each object contains two fields code and name.

I tried with following linq expression

```
 var anonList = (from u in xDoc.Descendants("LanguageList").DescendantNodes()
                   select u).ToList();
```

this is giving all nodes under LanguageList like

```
   <Language code = "EN-US" name = "English - United Sates"></Language>
   <Language code = "EN-UK" name = "English - United Kingdom"></Language>
```

I tried adding some where clauses and other ways.. but not able to get it. can anyone help

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get the attribute of each node and create the anonymous object. Something like this:

```
var listOfLanguages = xDoc.Descendants("LanguageList").Descendants()
                          .Select(l => new
                          {
                              Name = l.Attribute("name").Value,
                              Code = l.Attribute("code").Value
                          });
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of selecting "u", select something like "new { Code = u.Attribute("code").Value, Name = u.Attribute("name").Value }".

Answer (score 0):

Building on the code you have :

```
var anonList = (from u in xDoc.Descendants("LanguageList")
                              .Elements("Language")
                select new 
                       { 
                          Name = (string)u.Attribute("name"),
                          Code = (string)u.Attribute("code")
                       }
                ).ToList();
```

1. Use `Elements()` instead of `DescendantNodes()` to get *children elements*. 2. You can cast an `XAttribute` directly to `string`.